# Sorting 2D Array of Strings in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I need to sort an array of Strings in C. Here's how I'm using the 2D Array:

I, first, declare the array of size 115 with each element of the array having a capacity of 10 characters:
`char stock[115][10];`

Then, as soon as the user enters a word that I need to put into this array, I store it like:

```
strcpy(stock[r],msg);
r++;
```

Where **msg** is the temporary variable used to store the user input and **r** is an integer initially assigned to 0.

Now the issue is when I need to print the **Stock** array. I need the output to be in a alphabetical order. I tried using qsort but could not get it to work, probably I didn't quite implement it properly due to lack of understanding of qsort.

Please suggest a method to sort the **STOCK** array so that I can print the expected output.

Also note that the usual printing of Stock Array is working fine, ie, if i try to print the array in order in which it was stored, it works fine. It's the sorting with which I need help.

Thanks :)

Edit01: The QSORT Method that I'm trying to use here is:

```
//Call Qsort Method
qsort(stock, r, sizeof(stock[0]), comp);



//Function to Compare two Strings - Used in the QSORT Method
int comp(const void *s1, const void *s2)
{
    return (strcmp(*(char **)s1, *(char **)s2));
}
```

Comment: `qsort` is your friend.  Post your `qsort` code perhaps?

Comment: you can try to store your strings in the alphabetical order in the moment when you enter new string in the **stock** array

Comment: If you know the size of the strings (10), why use strcpy instead of strncpy?

Comment: strncpy doesn't guarantee to terminate the string, so care is needed if using it.

Comment: @William, right. But strcpy doesn't guarantee it will stop after 9 characters + terminating null. :)

Comment: +1 for your approach of using `sizeof(stock[0])` instead of hard coding the value. I liked this approach. I am learning C and your example set the standards for me to look at. BRILLIANT :-)

Comment: Thanks for the compliment..I'm glad it helped :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the prototype of `qsort`:

```
void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size, 
           int(*compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

- `base` is your array (`stock` here).
- `nmemb` is the number of members of your array (`r` here).
- `size` is the size of an element (`10` here).

The `compar` function should compare two strings, and return an integer less than, equal to,  or greater  than  zero  if  the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second. `strcmp` can do it for you.

```
#include <string.h>

int cmp(const void *a, const void *b) { 
    return strcmp(a, b); 
}

qsort(stock, r, 10, cmp);
```

Comment: Your `cmp` function is equivalent to `strcmp`. Just use `qsort(stock, r, 10, strcmp);`?

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: `strcmp` and `compare` prototypes are not the same. In the best-case scenario, you need a function pointer cast. In the worst-case scenario, it is an undefined behavior, because `const char *` and `const void *` are not compatible types.

Comment: @Kirilenko what you said is true for c++. But i think it would be fine with c since it does not require explicit casts and we are always passing c strings in this scenario